# How do I run shell commands on a remote server with Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell, sftp

Is there a way in a Ruby script to sftp to a server and run some commands.

Here is my script

```
Net::SFTP.start(IP_ADDRESS, 'root', :keys => ["/Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa"]) do |sftp|
    sftp.mkdir! "/srv/new_dir"
    sftp.dir.foreach("/srv/crm/current") do |entry|
      puts entry.longname
      sftp.file.open("/srv/new_dir", "w") do |f|
        f.puts entry
      end
    end
end
```

Basically I am trying to sftp to the server and copy a folder into a new folder and I would like to restart apache. I tried this:

```
FileUtils::sudo "/etc/init.d/apache2 reload"
```

but that doesn't work. Any ideas what I am doing wrong, or whether this is even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you aren't really doing any file transfers, I don't think you need to be using SFTP. You could simply rewrite this script using [`Net::SSH`](http://net-ssh.github.com/ssh/v2/api/index.html). Then you have normal access to a shell and your Apache command is simply another step in this process.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/).

**UPDATE:**

Capistrano is designed for deploying rails applications, but you can use it as a tool to manage remote machines. With a simple recipe, you can get your job done.

Suppose you have a Capfile like this:

```
desc "sample recipe"
task :sample do
    Dir.glob('**/*') do |f|
        upload f, "tmp/#{f}" 
    end
    run 'ls -lr'
end

role :app, "host name or ip"
set :user, "user_name"
```

Then you can run `cap sample` to upload files and run any commands.

It might be overkill, but it's much easier than using the Net APIs.

Comment: would you alter the script...what would you do to use capistrano....cap is for deploying rails applications